# How to set the wordpress locale in an external script?

Tags: wordpress

In order to use certain getText functions built into wordpress, the locale must be changed to the right languages to be used.

However, I can't seem to set the right language.

Here is a small script to demonstrate:

```
<?php
    require_once '../../../wp/wp-blog-header.php';
    $locale = 'pt_BR';
    echo get_locale();
    exit;
```

Expected result: pt_BR

Actual result: en_US

$locale is the global variable that holds the language code, that is why I expected it to work.

How can I set the locale to pt_BR so that when I use the translate functions, they will work as though the site is in Brazillian, rather than English ?

Comment: What's the value of `WPLANG` const in your `config.php`?

Comment: It's just an empty string, and the site's default language is English.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_og_og_locale', 'my_locale_filter' );
function my_locale_filter( $locale ) {
  return "en_BR";
}
```

This might help you.

Cheers!!

Comment: and you need wordpress by seo plugin installed for this code to get worked. :)